# Why am I getting a 'data will be truncated' exception?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I've got some code that executes a stored procedure, which in turn just runs an INSERT + SELECT to feed back to the calling data adapter

```
Public Function mGetDataSet_Trans(ByVal aStrQuery As String, ByRef aObjDS As DataSet, ByVal aStrDSName As String, ByVal aCon As SqlConnection, ByRef aTrans As SqlTransaction) As Boolean

    Dim pObjDataAdaptor As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

    mGetDataSet_Trans = False

    Try
      pObjDataAdaptor.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(aStrQuery, aCon, aTrans)
      pObjDataAdaptor.Fill(aObjDS, aStrDSName)
      mGetDataSet_Trans = True

    Catch SqlExp As SqlException
      //do stuff

      Throw SqlExp
    End Try
End Function
```

Nothing too complicated; create a data adapter, give it a command and connection, fill a New dataset object passed by reference and if there's an exception then roll back the transaction.

The `aStrQuery` basically looks like this:

```
    "EXECUTE USPSave 

    @FID='1090802', 
    @PID='4739933', 
    @aAType='4', 
    @aADate='6/1/2015 12:00:00 AM', 
    @aDiag1='ABC.12', 
    @aDiag2='ABC.12', 
    @aDiag3='ABC.12AB', 
    @aChangedBy='123'"

    // SELECT ... FROM myTable WHERE FID = @FID
```

In `USPSave`, `@aDiagX` is a `VARCHAR(10)` so there's no problem there. The table that gets updated also defines the fields are `VARCHAR(10)` which also shouldn't be a problem.

I have absolutely no idea where this exception could be coming from, but it is that `Fill` call in the `TRY` block throwing the exception. Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your stored procedure and relevant tables ddl.

Comment: I would suggest using a parameter collection instead of passing in a whole string to execute. They way this is written it is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @SeanLange `aStrQuery` is built securely-- it wasn't just some concatenated string ripped from the UI..

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it was just some string. I was suggesting you pass a parameter collection so you can easily build properly parameterized statements. This would also fix the issue because you know how long the data is for each parameter.

Comment: @SeanLange Ohh, I misunderstood. I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 2):

There's not a lot to go on but here's a guess:

"the fields are VARCHAR(10) "

"@aADate='6/1/2015 12:00:00 AM', "

I think the aADate field is too long and you are being told it will be truncated.